# Instance variable in linked list

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, nodes, instance-variables

I have written a program about patients. I have my own linked list collection class. **I could have used Java's linked list but the idea of my program is to get practice and get to know more about how linked list works.**

Here is a code snippet of my program.

```
class PatientList {
 private PatientNode head;
 private int lastArrival;
 private int size;

 public PatientList() {
  head = null;
  lastArrival = 0;
  size = 0;
 }

 public void add(String name, int severity) {
  //PatientNode previous;
  Patient patient;

  lastArrival++;
  patient = new Patient(name, lastArrival, severity);

  head = new PatientNode(patient, head);
  size++;
 }
```

Now, my problem is with the `size` instance variable. I seem to get `0` no matter what. However when i try to calculate `size` in the `print` method i get the `size` value right. Here is my `print` method code:

```
public void print() {
 PatientNode current;
 //int size = 0;

 current = head;
 while (current != null) {
  System.out.println(current.data);
  //size++;
  current = current.next;
 }

 System.out.println("Size = " + size()); //size() method actually returns size.
 System.out.println("Last arrival = " + lastArrival);
}
```

Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong when i am using instance variable? I just don't understand why would it print `0` when i am incrementing the `size` each time something is added to the list.

**Edit**

The size method is here in case that helps you help me solve the problem.

```
public int size() {
 return size;
}
```

**Edit 2**

```
String[] names = { "Zelma", "Clayton", "Casper", "Ihor", "Edwina" };
int[] severities = { 1, 2, 3, 1, 3 };
PatientList list;

list = new PatientList();
testPatientList(list, names, severities, 0);
}

public static void testPatientList(PatientList list, String[] names, int[] severities, int pos) {
 PatientList copy;

 if (pos < names.length) {
  list.add(names[pos], severities[pos]);
  copy = list.clone();

  copy.print();
  System.out.println("Admitting: " + copy.nextAdmission());
  System.out.println();

  testPatientList(list, names, severities, pos + 1);
  testPatientList(copy, names, severities, pos + 1);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the `size` method, please?  Your `print` method doesn't use the `size` variable at all, at least not directly.  It uses a **method** named `size`, but you haven't bothered to let us see it.

Comment: i just added the `size` method. it still prints `0` regardless of whether i use instance variable or the `size` method. @ajb

Comment: Are you sure you're atleast calling PatientList.add once?

Comment: `list = new PatientList();`  and this is the patients list `String[] names = { "Zelma", "Clayton", "Casper", "Ihor", "Edwina" };`  and this is how i am calling the list and adding the data `if (pos < names.length) {
   list.add(names[pos], severities[pos]);` @MrKickkiller

Comment: @Saad Could you perhaps add the calling code fully? Because with just the if, I can't guess if you're actually calling the code. Could be that pos is set to a value > names.length when running. So it never runs the list.add

Comment: If i wasn't calling `list.add` then why would it print the correct size in the `print` method.

Comment: i just added the calling code. @MrKickkiller

Comment: @Saad: Is PatientNode.next a public field even? (Just going over your code and trying to spot oddities that could explain your trouble)

Comment: Have you tried debuging by placing a `println` below the `size++`?

Comment: Never-mind guys i was able to solve it. The problem was in the clone method. Thank you for your time though. @MrKickkiller

Comment: I was able to find the bug. i just posted my answer below. Thanks for your time. @493msi

Comment: @Saad, No idea it this is by design, but your first added element will be at the back of the list (so costs linear time to fetch), while the most recent one would be a constant cost. So you're essentially creating a Stack, that is internally using a LinkedList. See: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62710/stack-implementation-using-a-linked-list

Next to that: Try to encapsulate as much as you can. Your first instinct when making a class/object variable/field should be private. Only when you investigate (after compile error), you can up the 'security' level to package private etc

Comment: Gotcha, i will try to redesign my linked list class according to that. Thanks for your suggestion :) @MrKickkiller

Comment: This is not the final version so that's why it is less than perfect. I have to modify the `add` method so that it adds according to the highest severity. In my program i have 3 as the highest and 1 as the lowest so(highest to lowest). Currently working on the `add` method. @MrKickkiller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it. The problem was with the deep copy i was making of the list. I wasn't doing anything for the size there.

```
public PatientList clone() {
 PatientList copy;
 PatientNode current;
 PatientNode copyCurrent;
 PatientNode newNode;

 copy = new PatientList();
 current = head;
 copyCurrent = null;
 while (current != null) {
  newNode = new PatientNode(current.data, null);
  if (copyCurrent == null) {
   copy.head = newNode;
  } else {
   // last node in copy points to the new node
     copyCurrent.next = newNode;
  }
 // move to the next node in both lists
  copyCurrent = newNode;
  current = current.next;
}
 copy.lastArrival = lastArrival;
 copy.size = size; // had to add this line

 return copy;
}
```

Comment: That one probably should have raised a red flag for me, since I rarely do use .clone(), but ok anyone can miss a thing or two :P